# Starting a PM2 process as a user with root privileges

Tags: node.js, pm2

Here's the problem, my node app requires root privileges to use `os.setPriority` on child processes.

So I need to run the app with sudo, but I want my .pm2 folder to remain in my /home/user directory so my user can access the log files, not /root.

If I run `pm2 start app.js` as user, no root privileges.

If I run `sudo pm2 start app.js` it saves under /root/.pm2 (inaccessible log files for user)

If I run `sudo PM2_HOME=/home/user/.pm2 pm2 start app.js` I still don't have permission to use os.setPriority! And if I run `sudo pm2 ls` afterwards it's not there, it runs on the user daemon. The only difference to this command and the first is when I run `pm2 ls` as the user, it lists the process as 'root' under the user column.

Any ideas?

Comment: If your main concern is just being able to view the logs, then why not just use run PM2 with `sudo` and the `--logs [path]` option to push the logs to a folder that both the root user and your privileged user have access to?

Answer (score 0):

save this as process.json
and then use `sudo pm2 start process.json`
Ref: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/

```json
    {
          script: 'app.js',
          error_file: '/home/user/.pm2/log/err.log',
          out_file: '/home/user/.pm2/log/out.log',
          log_file: '/home/user/.pm2/log/combined.log'
        }
```